# how to move child object inside a moving parent in unity2d using Vector2.MoveTowards()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nested, position

The Parent object is a moving rectangle and inside the rectangle there is another rectangle. the parent moving to right continuously and the child rectangle moving up and down.
[image]

(I Nested The Child into The Parent)

NOW:

I need the child move just inside the parent and don't cross the borders of its parent by using Vector2.MoveTowards()?

UPDATE #1 : the MoveToPoint Script

```
public float speed = .5f;
public Vector2 moveToPoint;

void Update()
{
    //moveToPoint = transform.InverseTransformPoint (moveToPoint);
    transform.localPosition = Vector2.MoveTowards(new Vector2(transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y), 
    new Vector2(transform.parent.transform.position.x + moveToPoint.x, transform.parent.transform.position.y + moveToPoint.y), speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

the script simply moves the gameobject that attached to, to the point specified. but the issue is when the gameobject is a child of a moving object the script move it to the original point before moving!

in another word I need to move the child in its local position...

Comment: Child the object the moves up and down to an empty gameobject that stays in place, and then child the empty gameobject to the parent, maybe?

Comment: @BrandonMiller in fact i wrote a script that moves an object to specific point using Vector2.MoveTowards(). and when i attach this script to a moving gameobject it moves that gameobject to its first destination position. i want it to move the object relative to its parent

Comment: What kind of gameobject are the rectangles? Do they have any kind of collider attached to them?

Comment: @ZayedUpal no collider attached to parent and child. i just need a way to move the child up and down relative to its moving parent. please see update1 above.